# Unable to see images or screenshots of applications in Software Center

Tags: image-processing

In the Ubuntu Software Center app, I am unable to see images of each application or the screenshots:

[image: screenshot of example of issue]

Do you know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Providing release details may help.